# Can i send id value with javaScript textbox's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to find top value and left value using td id but i must take textbox value and i must send to find Help me please.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {

        var _t1 = $("#t1").val();
        var _t2 = $("#t2").val();//users write values ​​like 'A2' 'B8' here
        //alert("Values:" + _t1 + ' ' + _t2); 

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var value = $("#B5"); //I need to send TextBox's value instead of 
            writing like this
            var offset = value.offset();
            //alert("x : " + offset.top + " y : " + offset.left);

            <tr>
               <td>5</td>
                <td class="d" id="A5"></td>
                <td class="w" id="B5"></td>
                <td class="d" id="C5"></td>
                <td class="w" id="D5"></td>
                <td class="d" id="E5"></td>
                <td class="w" id="F5"></td>
                <td class="d" id="G5"></td>
                <td class="w" id="H5"></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Where is the textbox?

Comment: I didnt send all codes. Its not necessary for this status.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `t2` is your textbox, you would want something like this:

`var td = $('#' + $('#t2').val());`

What this does is it appends the value of the textbox to the '#' character and then passes this concatenated string for jQuery as a selector.

Using the notations from above:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var inputtedID = $("#t2").val();
    if (inputtedID) {
      //check that it is not an empty string

      var td = $("#" + inputtedID);
      if (td.length > 0) {
        //if there is a td with that ID
        var offset = td.offset();
        $("#result").text("The offset for " + inputtedID + ": {top: " + offset.top + ", left: " + offset.left + "}");
      } else {
        $("#result").text("There is no element with id of " + inputtedID);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td{
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="d" id="A5"></td>
    <td class="w" id="B5"></td>
    <td class="d" id="C5"></td>
    <td class="w" id="D5"></td>
    <td class="d" id="E5"></td>
    <td class="w" id="F5"></td>
    <td class="d" id="G5"></td>
    <td class="w" id="H5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input id="t2" />

<button id="button">Get Offset</button>
<br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can i ask more one questions ? I want to select image under td. Mean, How can I choose the image that want in this code( var td = $("#" + inputtedID); ) Just there is a one image and images havent id.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solved your problem consider marking the answer as accepted. As for your other question, if the image is inside the `td` element, and there's only one image, then you'd have to write `var image = td.find("img");`. You can read more on `.find()` here: https://api.jquery.com/find/